# Autocomplete ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I´m using jquery ui autocomplete. The autocomplete source is coming from an ajax request.
Then, when the user clicks in an option, I made another ajax request to get the data related to that option from the server.

Erveything works fine, except that after the second ajax request, when i type something in the autocomplete box it shows me the data which i got in the second request.

The second request´s data is **overriding** the data of the first one...

**It shows the result of the second requestin the placeholder. However after that, when you type again in the autocomplete it takes the data coming in the success request as it´s source! The last data is being used as the autocomplete source!**

Could you help me solving this issue?

Here´s my code:

```
$("#sinput").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'Handlers/AutoCompleteHandler.ashx?type=html',
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {

                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.label,
                                id: item.value,
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var content_id = ui.item.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'Handlers/GetContentHandler.ashx?id=' + content_id + '&type=html',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#placeholder').html(data[0].label)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

While returning the data for the second AJAX request from the server, try some other name instead of 'label'.